# Cast string to either int or float

Tags: php, string, casting, numeric

I'm looking for a function that would cast a numeric-string into either integer or float type depending on the content of the string, e.g. "1.23" -> float 1.23, "123" -> int 123.

I know I can use if-s with is_int, is_float and cast to appropriate types - but maybe there is a function that would do it automatically?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, no function provides the automatic cast. However you can cast with this simple hack (the cast is automatically made by PHP in internal):

```
$int = "123"+0;
$float = "1.23"+0;
```

for generic number:

```
$yourNumberCasted = $yourStringNumber + 0;
```

With a function:

```
function castToNumber($genericStringNumber) { 
    return $genericStringNumber+0; 
}
$yourNumberCasted = castToNumber($yourStringNumber);
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution.  I was thinking down the route of a `ternary if` to detect the presence of a ".", and then using `(int)` or `(float)`.  Yours is a very elegant solution, but one which I would be inclined to comment in code as it's not obvious to the reader what it does.

Comment: You can create a function with a title "castToNumber" if you prefer. `function castToNumber($genericStringNumber) { return $genericStringNumber+0; }`

Comment: Do keep in mind that very large integers will be converted to floats when using this method, depending on PHP_INT_MAX setting for your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can fulfil your requirement using following line.

```
 $i = "1.23";       
 echo $c = (double)$i; // will return 1.23

 $i = "123";       
 echo $c = (double)$i; // will return 123
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function to do that but you can create your own quickly.

```
function castNumber($n)
{
   if(!is_numeric($n)) return 0;
   return (is_float($n)) ? (float) $n : (int) $n;
}
```

and use it:

```
$casted = castNumber($num_to_cast);
```

Comment: more or less, this is what I have. I just hoped there is something like that built-in.

Comment: I always have a Utils.php file where I add functions like these when there is not a built-in functions for what I want and then reuse it on my applications

Comment: just like underscore.js for javascript ;)

Comment: since `is_float()` will always return false on strings, this function will always cast a numeric string to an int

Comment: Maybe if you change the return line to `return (is_float($n + 0)) ? (float) $n : (int) $n;`, it would be work better

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. But here is my solution:

`$numString = '1.0';
$intOrFloat = (strpos($numString, '.') !==false) ? floatval($numString) : intval($numString);`

Comment: This one is `strict` to follow our coding standarts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your incoming value is dirty (e.g. user-provided) and so not guaranteed to be numeric, as of PHP 8.0 the accepted solution will generate `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int` where previously it was just a warning.

You can drop an `is_numeric()` in there and provide an explicit 0 value for non-numerics

```
function castToNumber($genericStringNumber) { 
    return is_numeric($genericStringNumber) ? $genericStringNumber + 0 : 0
}
```

Alternatively you could explicitly cast with something like

```
function castToNumber($genericStringNumber) { 
    return ((int)$genericStringNumber == (float)$genericStringNumber)
        ? (int)$genericStringNumber
        : (float)$genericStringNumber; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

○

```
function castToNumber1($genericStringNumber) { 
    return ((int)$genericStringNumber == (float)$genericStringNumber)
        ? (int)$genericStringNumber
        : (float)$genericStringNumber; 
}
```

×

```
function castToNumber2($genericStringNumber) { 
    return is_numeric($genericStringNumber) ? $genericStringNumber + 0 : 0;
}
```

bad case

```
// $hoge is float
$hoge = castToNumber2(1.2E+2); // 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is quite old, I would like to add a new solution to the problem. Definetely the best answer is the one provided by antoox however, as already pointed, it has a small drawback... it is not clear what a "+ 0" is doing.

One concise solution which is self explanatory would be:

```
$intOrFloat = floatval($str) ? (float)$str : (int)$str;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a function [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) which does almost the same thing as type-casting mentioned in other answers, however it can't be used on objects.

Also having same functionality: [`boolval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) and [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

Comment: I don't want int - but int or float

Comment: Ok, so use the trick with adding `0` (or multiplying by `1`).